# event.preventDefault( ) is NOT working in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, preventdefault

**Unable to get values in console!
What am I doing it incorrectly?**

Attached below is the functional component of React

**The Handler Functions**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const SimpleInput = (props) => {
  const nameInputRef = useRef();
  const [enteredName, setEnteredName] = useState('');

  const nameInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredName(event.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmissionHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(enteredName);

    const enteredName = nameInputRef.current.value;
    console.log(enteredName);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <div className="form-control" onSubmit={formSubmissionHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Your Name</label>
        <input
          ref={nameInputRef}
          type="text"
          id="name"
          onChange={nameInputChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-actions">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SimpleInput;
```

Comment: Add `onSubmit={formSubmissionHandler}` on the `form` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formSubmissionHandler` should have on the `form` element rather than the `div` element.

```
 return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmissionHandler}>
      <div className="form-control">
        <label htmlFor="name">Your Name</label>
        <input
          ref={nameInputRef}
          type="text"
          id="name"
          onChange={nameInputChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-actions">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```